# Implementing react with express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, reactjs, pug

I'm trying to convert a basic express-generator app with a couple of routes into a react app on the front end. Later I might upgrade that to React/Redux.

I currently have Jade set up as the templating engine (by default) and a `/api` set of routes that I want to keep accessible for data, and some routes for the views which I would like to change (I don't care about using Jade).

What is the best way to achieve this? I've been reading around various articles but there are so many possibilities that I'm getting confused.

On the react side, if I don't use react-router will my app still be single paged?

Thanks!

Comment: This is way too broad. There is no single path between an Express app and a React app. Also a React client-side app can still reuse parts of the Express server-side app.

Comment: I know it's broad, I'm just stuck on how to proceed and get the basics working

Answer (score 1):

Use starter project, fonctionnal configuration right their!

https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit